# Finding a string in a file

Tags: python

I am attempting to rename a file with a known string from inside the file.
I can get the information I want from the file, in my output from searching the file. I cannot get the information I am after if it has an extra  carriage return. Here is the code:

```
>>> with open('c:/test/277coreB.txt', 'r') as config:
...     for line in config:
...            if "hostname" in line:
...                     host = line
...     #This is where the extra carriage return come from and I cannot get rid of it
>>> print host[9:]
XR77-2-DC-Core-B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.rstrip('\n')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) will get rid of the trailing newline.

Comment: That was so fast, I appreciate the help. that was the fix.

Comment: You could also just use `host = line.strip()`, which will strip all whitespace (including newlines) at the beginning and end of `line`.